# variance probability

Tags: probability

A fair coin is tossed 4 times. let $x$ be the number of times a head is immediately followed by a tail then $V_x =$?.
My try: from the sample space $p=\frac{12}{16}$

$ V_x= npq = 16(12/16)(4/16)=3 $

however $V_x$ does not match any options given.

Help required.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be assuming that the distribution is a binomial distribution, which is not the case.

You need to find the actual distribution of $x$ by listing the cases. I find that the possible values of $x$ are $0, 1, 2$ with probabilities $5/16, 10/16$ and $1/16$. From that you should be able to calculate the mean and variance of the distribution, but I will will give further details if needed.

I found the possible values of $x$ and the associated probabilities as follows:

$x$ will be zero if there are no heads immediately followed by a tail (hhhh, thhh, tthh, ttth, tttt) so that $P(x=0)=5/16$

$x$ will be $2$ in only one case (htht), so that $P(x=2)=1/16$.

Clearly then, $P(x=1)=10/16$.

Comment: got it...many thanks